# How to crawl a web page using selenium - find_element_by_link_text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium and **BeautifulSoup** to "click" a `javascript.void`. The return of `find_element_by_link_text` is not **NULL**. However, nothing is updated by reviewing `browser.page_source`. I am not sure if crawling is success or not

Here is the result using

```
PageTable = soup.find('table',{'id':'rzrqjyzlTable'})
print(PageTable)
```

```
 <table class="tab1" id="rzrqjyzlTable">
 <div id="PageNav" class="PageNav" style="">
 <div class="Page" id="PageCont">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" class="nolink">Previous</a>3<span class="at">1</span>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Page 2">2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Page 3">3</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Page 4">4</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Page 5">5</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Next group" class="next">...</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Last Page">45</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self" title="Page 2">Next Page</a>
  <span class="txt">&nbsp;&nbsp;Jump</span><input class="txt" id="PageContgopage">
  <a class="btn_link">Go</a></div>
                        </div>
```

The code for clicking next page is shown below

```
try:       
    page = browser.find_element_by_link_text(u'Next Page')
    page.click()    
    browser.implicitly_wait(3)
  except NoSuchElementException:
    print("NoSuchElementException")

  soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
  PageTable = soup.find('table',{'id':'rzrqjyzlTable'})
  print(PageTable )
```

I am expecting that browser.page_source should be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are pulling the source before the page (or subpage) is done reloading. I would try grabbing the Next Page button, click it, wait for it to go stale (indicates the page is reloading), and then try pulling the source.

```
page = browser.find_element_by_link_text(u'Next Page')
page.click()
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(page))
# the page should be loading/loaded at this point
# you may need to wait for a specific element to appear to ensure that it's loaded properly since it doesn't seem to be a full page load
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. However, I don't know why  it keep running when using WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, u'Next Page')))

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on Next page, you can reload the web page.

**Code :**

```
driver.refresh()
```

Or using Java script executor :

```
driver.execute_script("location.reload()")
```

after that you try to get the page source like the way you are doing.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both but fails. Whenever refreshing, even in the browser e.g chrome, the first page will be shown again :(

Comment: Can you try with `browser.get(browser.current_url)` , what does that return ? Does it return the old url or new url ?

Comment: The URL won't change. When clicking, only the 'framecontent' will be updated. I think it is designed intentionally.

Comment: I guess, reload should work in that case, after reload try to wait for sometime and then check page source.

Comment: '''browser.refresh()
  #browser.execute_script("location.reload()")  
  browser.implicitly_wait(5)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
  PageTable = soup.find('table',{'id':'rzrqjyzlTable'})
  print(PageTable )''' I've already added, nothing change :(

Comment: Can you try with explicit wait ? `time.sleep()`

Comment: Sure and already tried but fail. No matter how long to wait, e.g. sleep(3), sleep(120)